# Is better to use separate DB for login and table content in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, database

I want to try learning make a simple website with login page and content page that have just show a table. I know that it's just a simple web, but I want to know when I join a project with multiple pages and tables in the future, what is the best reason to use multi-DB scenario. And what is common trouble/error when use multi-DB. I hope someone give me a good reference for my decision in the future what is the best scenario to build the project.
Thank you!

Comment: You can use a dedicated schema for Authentification, but you can also go ahead and user an identity provider (IdP) like keycloak https://www.keycloak.org/. Why you need mutli-DB ? For what goal ?Maybe mutli tenancy ?

Comment: Honestly my goal is want to know and open my perspective why in project which have so many tables just use one DB, is there any cons for using multi DB ?

Comment: It depends or relations if tables have relations its need to be in same DB (schema). If there is no relation you have the choice, but it could be more complicate to manage lot of connection definition.

Comment: ooh I see, so is more efficient if the tables has a relations right? . Then what is the example or case that the tables has no relations? and how do I know the tables in a project is not have relations?

Comment: https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/sqlserver/tables-relations it's your business model that involve relations or not between entities.